# nodeMCU DeepSleep Configuration

Tags: http, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am working on configuring the WeMos D1 Mini running nodeMCU so that it makes http post once every minute and then go to deepsleep, repeat. I have pin32 & pin8 connected with jumper cable as specified by the nodeMCU documentation. When I run the following code (omitting deepsleep), it works fine but not when I include the deepsleep code, then it fails to make any http post all together, any help would be appreciated.

```
init.lua
-- configure network 
dofile("credentials.lua")

-- dht22 sensor for humidity&temperature 
dht22 = 5
status, temp, humi, temp_dec, humi_dec = dht.read(dht22)

    if status == dht.OK then
        -- for debugging, print to console 
        print("DHT Temperature: "..temp)
        print("DHT Humidity: "..humi)
    elseif status == dht.ERROR_CHECKSUM then
        print( "DHT Checksum error." )
    elseif status == dht.ERROR_TIMEOUT then
        print( "DHT timed out." )
    end

-- post request 
http.post('url',
  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n',
  '{"humidity":'..humi..', "temperature":'..temp..', "moisture":'..adc.read(0)..', "sunlight":0}',
  function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)

-- small delay to allow the device to make http post before going into deep-sleep mode 
tmr.delay(5000000)
print("enterning deep sleep mode for 60 seconds...goodbye")
node.dsleep(60000000)


credentials.lua 
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("ssid","pwd")

tmr.alarm(1, 10000, 1, function()
    if wifi.sta.getip()== nil then
        print("Awaiting IP...")
    else
        tmr.stop(1)
        print("IP: "..wifi.sta.getip())
        print("Proceeding...")
        dofile("init.lua")
    end
end)
```

Comment: 10 seconds of delay too much to poll wifi connectivity

Comment: You should post to the network by ensuring that you have connectivity.

Comment: Send device to sleep when you got response from server

Comment: @cagdas, thank you, how do I delay sleep until response from server is received? I was told tmr.delay() is a bad idea as it busy loops the ESP processor, any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> When I run the following code (omitting deepsleep), it works fine but not when I include the deepsleep code, then it fails to make any http post all together

I don't understand...you do *not* omit deep sleep in your code sample, do?

Anyway, `tmr.delay` is a no-go especially with anything beyond 50us. Why don't you enter deep sleep when the HTTP request returns? Something like this:

```
http.post('url',
  'Content-Type: application/json\r\n',
  '{"humidity":'..humi..', "temperature":'..temp..', "moisture":'..adc.read(0)..', "sunlight":0}',
  function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
      print("enterning deep sleep mode for 60 seconds...goodbye")
      node.dsleep(60000000)
    end
  end)
```

Comment: Hello @marcel Thank you for the information & Structure Guidance.

I tried the changes you recommended above but no joy.
The problem I am currently experiencing is that when the ESP makes a successful post (I can verify on the server / database side) it prints the following to the console: 
"HTTP client: Disconnected with error: 8"
"HTTP client: Connection timeout"
"HTTP client: Connection timeout"

I've tried numerous ways to try and get it to execute node.dsleep() to no avail, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Appears to be (at least related to) https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1707.

Comment: Try to POSTing to a dummy resource such as https://requestb.in so that this question can then be accepted/closed.